# SanDisk USB Speed Claims 150 mb/sec

Tags: usb, ssd

I get very different speeds when writing from the USB compared to writing from the USB to my desktop.

My desktop has an SSD, class 40 and when writing data from the desktop to the USB, speeds are around 20mb/s but when I write from the USB to the desktop, they are around 150mb/s.

Any ideas why that's the case? Please refer to both screenshots below. I used the same file type and roughly the same file size.

I have the SanDisk 64GB Ultra Luxe USB 3.1 Gen 1 Flash Drive
[https://www.amazon.com/SanDisk-64GB-Ultra-Flash-Drive/dp/B07SSZ8W38](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SSZ8W38)

[image: transfer speed from Desktop to USB]

[image: Transfer speed from USB to Desktop]

Comment: Typically, copying data from the PC to an external disk or USB stick, 
is slower than copying data from an external disk or USB stick to the PC.

Comment: What sandisk USB do you have? I've been trying to go checking the Sandisk sites - but all they promote are only "READ" speed at whatever speed they claim (150MB/s) ... they never said anything about WRITE speed. Some review sites usually found read speed is higher than write speed. Usually the difference between read and write speed is not too big, but since now the write speed is no longer documented....

Comment: i've updated my main question with the model

Comment: @Ahmad I've added a section to the bottom of my answer for your stick. They claim up to 150MB/s **read** but only a vague hand-wave towards "up to 15 x faster than a 4MB/s USB2 stick" with the key words being "up to". Gotta love marketing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it likely claims is "up to 150MB/s ***read speed***" with the "read speed" in the small print.

Writing data to flash memory is **hard**. It requires, at minimum, a higher voltage to drive electrons onto a floating gate in the flash cell in order to register a 1 or a 0. For multi-level cells used in modern flash it must drive that gate to a subtly different voltage in order to register two or more bits of data. That extra precision means more (probably slower and more precise) control. In the worst case the cell needs to be erased first which means more time spent trying to empty the flash cell first before writing. This process is slow.

Reading on the other hand is easy. It is a sense of what is already in the flash cell. It is fast. It is also the "up to" speed that the manufacturer will give you because it makes the device look fast.

In the small print for the device should hopefully be an "expected" write speed.

For SD cards they have a speed rating that tells you the *minimum* worst case write speed for the device. The speed on modern cards is likely to be either U3 (written as a U with a 3 inside) or U1 denoting that the card can write a minimum of 30MB/s (U3) or 10MB/s (U1). This is the speed after cells are erased during writes which as mentioned are the slowest. The card may well be faster than that for writing, and should definitely read a lot faster, but that rating gives you a minimum performance guarantee for use in devices like video cameras which will be *constantly* writing to the device.

Beyond devices that specify minimum write speed as part of their design specifications the marketing blurb saying "up to 150MB/s" borders on meaningless and is a cherry picked specification to fool you into believing it will always be that fast for every use case.

Flash memory does not write as fast as it reads.

Note that the specifications for the [Sandisk Ultra USB3.0](https://shop.westerndigital.com/products/usb-flash-drives/sandisk-ultra-usb-3-0#SDCZ48-016G-A46) only lists the "sequential read speed" (from your USB to the computer) as 100MB/s. There is no mention at all of write speeds at all except for in the "disclosures" section where you will find

> write speed lower and varies by capacity

So you will almost certainly never see that 100MB/s for writing.

---

At the bottom of the product description your Amazon page there are several caveats about the speeds of the various versions of memory stick. It appears on the [manufacturer page](https://shop.westerndigital.com/products/usb-flash-drives/sandisk-ultra-luxe-usb-3-1#SDCZ74-016G-A46) (again in the "disclosures" section at the bottom) as well and states

> Read speeds up to 150MB/s. Write speed to drive **up to** 15X faster than standard USB 2.0 drives (4 MB/s).

You might only get 10 times their 4MB/s speed (40MB/s) or even only 5 times (20MB/s) but in legal language they are covered by saying "up to" because even small values below 15 are still some way "up to" 15.

So the only qualification on write speed is that you ***might*** get up to 60MB/s (15 x 4) if you have the same machine and model memory stick that they tested in their laboratory. Chances are they tested only the stick most likely to get the highest speed as on many other memory stick pages they also have a "speed varies by capacity" disclaimer.

It is difficult to know why you are getting only half the write speed that they have given as a possibility, but they are covered by saying "up to" some value. It is not a guaranteed minimum speed, it is a "you might get lucky and actually get this speed".